# How to declare a shell constant for Jenkins execute shell build configuration?

Tags: shell, jenkins

I'm running the following command in the "execute shell" entry in my Jenkins job configuration.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX CASS_HOSTNAME=XXX DB_HOSTNAME=XXX DB_PASSWORD=XXX DB_USERNAME=XXX EMAIL_REGION=XXX RED_HOSTNAME=XXXX RED_PORT=XXX npm run
```

How could I create a single variable for those parameters? I tried declaring a regular shell constant like:

```
readonly parameters="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX .."
$parameters npm run init_test_tenant
```

But I get the following error

/tmp/hudson6912171417213995775.sh: 4: /tmp/hudson6912171417213995775.sh: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX: not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid place `eval` in front of everything and [open a hole in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220), you can use a trick:

```
export $parameters
npm run init_test_tenant
```

The difference from the attempt in your question: all variables will be visible to `npm` and all other commands you would execute after that, while `VAR=value command` syntax let `VAR` visible only to `command`.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix with `env`

```
readonly parameters="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX .."
env $parameters npm run init_test_tenant
```

Also if you do not need any other environment variables in your **nodejs** program you can add the `-i` option to `env` so that you get a clean environment for `npm`, but then you would have to address `npm` via full path ( eg: `/usr/bin/npm` ) and all other programs that might run within you **nodejs** program:

```
readonly parameters="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX .."
env -i $parameters /usr/bin/npm run init_test_tenant
```

Or add the `PATH=/usr/bin/` to the `$parameters` constant like so:

```
readonly parameters="PATH=/usr/bin AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX .."
env -i $parameters npm run init_test_tenant
```